# PostgreSQL -must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.1, production

I am getting this error in the pg production mode, but its working fine in sqlite3 development mode.

```
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in ManagementController#index

PG::Error: ERROR:  column "estates.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT "estates".* FROM "estates"  WHERE "estates"."Mgmt" = ...
               ^
: SELECT "estates".* FROM "estates"  WHERE "estates"."Mgmt" = 'Mazzey' GROUP BY user_id

@myestate = Estate.where(:Mgmt => current_user.Company).group(:user_id).all
```

Comment: with GROUP BY in PostgreSQL, you cannot use column in selection list if you didn't use it in group by. Don't know how to translate it into rails

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19601948/398670

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601948/must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause-or-be-used-in-an-aggregate-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@myestate1 = Estate.where(:Mgmt => current_user.Company)
@myestate = @myestate1.select("DISTINCT(user_id)")
```

this is what I did.

Answer (score 47):

If `user_id` is the *PRIMARY KEY* then you need to upgrade PostgreSQL; newer versions will correctly handle grouping by the primary key.

If `user_id` is neither unique ***nor*** the primary key for the 'estates' relation in question, then this query doesn't make much sense, since PostgreSQL has no way to know *which* value to return for each column of `estates` where multiple rows share the same `user_id`. You must use an aggregate function that expresses what you want, like `min`, `max`, `avg`, `string_agg`, `array_agg`, etc or add the column(s) of interest to the `GROUP BY`.

Alternately you can rephrase the query to use `DISTINCT ON` and an `ORDER BY` if you really do want to pick a somewhat arbitrary row, though I really doubt it's possible to express that via ActiveRecord.

Some databases - including SQLite and MySQL - will just pick an arbitrary row. This is considered incorrect and unsafe by the PostgreSQL team, so PostgreSQL follows the SQL standard and considers such queries to be errors.

If you have:

```
col1    col2
fred    42
bob     9
fred    44
fred    99
```

and you do:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM mytable GROUP BY col1;
```

then it's obvious that you should get the row:

```
bob     9
```

but what about the result for `fred`? There is no single correct answer to pick, so the database will refuse to execute such unsafe queries. If you wanted the *greatest* `col2` for any `col1` you'd use the `max` aggregate:

```
SELECT col1, max(col2) AS max_col2 FROM mytable GROUP BY col1;
```

Comment: user_id is primary key in User table, but on in Estate table.

Comment: @HrishikeshSardar in which case this query doesn't make sense. Which Estate does it return for any given `user_id`? Pick one randomly? It won't do that. You have to use an aggregate or re-think what you're doing.

Comment: I am trying to figure out is like if I have @estate with values like {1,1,2,3,4,5,6,6}, but now i just want {1,2,3,4,5,6} from it, what should i do, in this example i have given u a array, but I want the same thing for array of hash

Comment: how i will translate this query "SELECT col1, max(col2) AS max_col2 FROM mytable GROUP BY col1;" into ruby ?

Comment: @HrishikeshSardar http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html . Oddly enough, the first hit for `"activerecord max"` in Google.

Answer (score 16):

I recently moved from MySQL to PostgreSQL and encountered the same issue. Just for reference, the best approach I've found is to use DISTINCT ON as suggested in this SO answer:

[Elegant PostgreSQL Group by for Ruby on Rails / ActiveRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512286/elegant-postgresql-group-by-for-ruby-on-rails-activerecord/4632070#4632070)

This will let you get one record for each unique value in your chosen column that matches the other query conditions:

```
MyModel.where(:some_col => value).select("DISTINCT ON (unique_col) *")
```

I prefer DISTINCT ON because I can still get all the other column values in the row. DISTINCT alone will only return the value of that specific column.

Comment: `DISTINCT ON` is useful, where appropriate. But the query planner isn't as smart with `DISTINCT ON` as with `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` so it's worth avoiding unless you actually need it. It's also nonstandard.

Answer (score 6):

After often receiving the error myself I realised that Rails (I am using rails 4) automatically adds an 'order by id' at the end of your grouping query. This often results in the error above. So make sure you append your own .order(:group_by_column) at the end of your Rails query. Hence you will have something like this:

```
@problems = Problem.select('problems.username, sum(problems.weight) as weight_sum').group('problems.username').order('problems.username')
```

Comment: I had the same (default_scope that ordered my model). So what I did is:
`Model.reorder(nil).group_by(...)` this way the order is removed.

Comment: this comment... should be the answer.