# must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate-functions, postgresql-9.1

I have a table that looks like this caller 'makerar'

| cname | wmname | avg |
| --- | --- | --- |
| canada | zoro | 2.0000000000000000 |
| spain | luffy | 1.00000000000000000000 |
| spain | usopp | 5.0000000000000000 |

And I want to select the maximum avg for each cname.

```
SELECT cname, wmname, MAX(avg)  FROM makerar GROUP BY cname;
```

but I will get an error,

```
ERROR:  column "makerar.wmname" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an   aggregate function 
LINE 1: SELECT cname, wmname, MAX(avg)  FROM makerar GROUP BY cname;
```

so i do this

```
SELECT cname, wmname, MAX(avg)  FROM makerar GROUP BY cname, wmname;
```

however this will not give the intented results, and the incorrect output below is shown.

| cname | wmname | max |
| --- | --- | --- |
| canada | zoro | 2.0000000000000000 |
| spain | luffy | 1.00000000000000000000 |
| spain | usopp | 5.0000000000000000 |

Actual Results should be

| cname | wmname | max |
| --- | --- | --- |
| canada | zoro | 2.0000000000000000 |
| spain | usopp | 5.0000000000000000 |

How can I go about fixing this issue?

Note: This table is a VIEW created from  a previous operation.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18061285/398670

Comment: I don't understand. Why is `wmname="usopp"` expected and not for example `wmname="luffy"`?

Comment: @AndreKR Because the max of (1, 5) is 5, and 5 is associated with "usopp", not with "luffy". That is the intended/desired result.

Comment: If the `avg` for `(spain, luffy)` is the same as for `(spain, usopp)`, then you need to specify what is the intended behavior... Choose one randomly? Use other columns as "tie-breakers"?

Answer (score 382, accepted):

Yes, this is a common aggregation problem. Before [SQL3 (1999)](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~len/sql1999.pdf), the selected fields must appear in the `GROUP BY` clause[*].

To workaround this issue, you must calculate the aggregate in a sub-query and then join it with itself to get the additional columns you'd need to show:

```
SELECT m.cname, m.wmname, t.mx
FROM (
    SELECT cname, MAX(avg) AS mx
    FROM makerar
    GROUP BY cname
    ) t JOIN makerar m ON m.cname = t.cname AND t.mx = m.avg
;

 cname  | wmname |          mx           
--------+--------+------------------------
 canada | zoro   |     2.0000000000000000
 spain  | usopp  |     5.0000000000000000
```

---

But you may also use window functions, which looks simpler:

```
SELECT cname, wmname, MAX(avg) OVER (PARTITION BY cname) AS mx
FROM makerar
;
```

The only thing with this method is that it will show all records (window functions do not group). But it will show the correct (i.e. maxed at `cname` level) `MAX` for the country in each row, so it's up to you:

```
 cname  | wmname |          mx           
--------+--------+------------------------
 canada | zoro   |     2.0000000000000000
 spain  | luffy  |     5.0000000000000000
 spain  | usopp  |     5.0000000000000000
```

The solution, arguably less elegant, to show the only `(cname, wmname)` tuples matching the max value, is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT /* distinct here matters, because maybe there are various tuples for the same max value */
    m.cname, m.wmname, t.avg AS mx
FROM (
    SELECT cname, wmname, avg, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY avg DESC) AS rn 
    FROM makerar
) t JOIN makerar m ON m.cname = t.cname AND m.wmname = t.wmname AND t.rn = 1
;


 cname  | wmname |          mx           
--------+--------+------------------------
 canada | zoro   |     2.0000000000000000
 spain  | usopp  |     5.0000000000000000
```

---

[*]: Interestingly enough, even though the spec sort of allows to select non-grouped fields, major engines seem to not really like it. Oracle and SQLServer just don't allow this at all. Mysql used to allow it by default, but now since 5.7 the administrator needs to enable this option (`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`) manually in the server configuration for this feature to be supported...

Comment: Thanks syntax is corect, but, you must compare values of mx and avg when joining

Comment: Yes your syntax is correct and eliminates duplicates however you need m.avg=t.mx in the end (after you wrote JOING) to get intended results

Comment: @Sebas It can be done without joining on `MAX` (see answer by @ypercube, there is also another solution in my answer) but not the way you do it. Check expected output.

Comment: @Sebas Your solution only adds a column (the MAX `avg` per `cname`) but it doesn't restrict the rows of the result (as the OP wants). See the **Actual Results should be** paragraph in the question.

Comment: @ypercube, the join by max value does give a result compatible with the expected results in the question. However, if 2 rows in a group have the same value for avg, both of them will be retrieved. I didn't see anything specifically discarding this use case though.

Comment: Turning _off_ `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` in MySQL 5.7 does not activate the way the SQL standard specifies when columns can be omitted from the `group by` (or makes MySQL behave like Postgres). It just reverts to the old behavior where MySQL returns random (= "indeterminate") results instead.

Comment: Is there any other solutions now? I am using aws athena

Comment: Note about the "self" `JOIN` sub-query: If the `avg` for `(spain, luffy)` is the same as for `(spain, usopp)`, then there is a "tie" and the final results would **include both cases**: `(canada, zoro 2.000), (spain,  usopp, 5.000), (spain,  luffy, 5.000)`

Comment: If you use the window function solution, there is no need for join. Simplified: `SELECT  t.cname, t.wmname, t.avg AS mx
FROM (
    SELECT cname, wmname, avg, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY avg DESC) AS rn 
    FROM makerar
) AS t WHERE t.rn = 1 ;`

Answer (score 182):

In Postgres, you can also use the special **[`DISTINCT ON (expression)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)** syntax:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (cname) 
    cname, wmname, avg
FROM 
    makerar 
ORDER BY 
    cname, avg DESC ;
```

Comment: It won't work as it's expected if one wants to sort columns like avg

Comment: @amenzhinsky What do you mean? If one wants to have the result set sorted with a different order than `BY cname` ?

Comment: @ypercube, Actually psql sorts first and then applies DISTINCT. In case of sorting by avg we'll get different results for every row minimal and maximal values depending on sort direction

Comment: Of course. If you don't run the query I posted, you'll get different results! That's not the same as "it won't work as expected"...

Comment: @Batfan thnx. Note that while this is quite cool, compact and easy to write, it's not often the most efficient way for this kind of queries.

Comment: Does it support in Redshift?

Comment: Although I really like the syntax, I've had trouble optimizing these queries, and it's easy to write suboptimal ones.  Perhaps I'm just missing something.

Comment: @EricWalker no you are not. While the syntax is nice and compact, it's very often not the most efficient way to write such queries. Perhaps I should add a note in my answer.

Comment: @Yubaraj no, it's not yet supported

Answer (score 75):

The problem with specifying non-grouped and non-aggregate fields in `group by` selects is that engine has no way of knowing which record's field it should return in this case. Is it first? Is it last? There is usually no record that naturally corresponds to aggregated result (`min` and `max` are exceptions).

However, there is a workaround: make the required field aggregated as well.
In postgres, this should work:

```
SELECT cname, (array_agg(wmname ORDER BY avg DESC))[1], MAX(avg)
FROM makerar GROUP BY cname;
```

Note that this creates an array of all wnames, ordered by avg, and returns the first element (arrays in postgres are 1-based).

Comment: Good point. Though it seems possible that the DB could do an outer join to link the non-aggregate fields from each row to the aggregated result to which the row contributed. I've often been curious why they don't have an option for that. Though I could simply be ignorant of this option :)

Comment: it's nice solution for pgsql, but any mysql equivalent? I don't like multi select way.

Comment: GREAT use of `array_agg` I didn't know you can sort right in the params

Comment: `array_agg` is what I was looking for to return all the items that the `GROUP BY` matches

Comment: In this case, `MAX(avg)` can be replaced with just `avg`because they may no different after having them sorted out by the aggregation before, right?

Answer (score 49):

For me, it is not about a "common aggregation problem", but just about an incorrect SQL query. The single correct answer for "select the maximum avg for each cname..." is

```
SELECT cname, MAX(avg) FROM makerar GROUP BY cname;
```

The result will be:

```
 cname  |      MAX(avg)
--------+---------------------
 canada | 2.0000000000000000
 spain  | 5.0000000000000000
```

This result in general answers the question *"What is the best result for each group?"*. We see that the best result for spain is 5 and for canada the best result is 2. It is true, and there is no error.
 If we need to display **wmname** also, we have to answer the question: "What is the **RULE** to choose wmname from resulting set?" Let's change the input data a bit to clarify the mistake:

```
  cname | wmname |        avg           
--------+--------+-----------------------
 spain  | zoro   |  1.0000000000000000
 spain  | luffy  |  5.0000000000000000
 spain  | usopp  |  5.0000000000000000
```

Which result do you expect on runnig this query: `SELECT cname, wmname, MAX(avg)  FROM makerar GROUP BY cname;`? Should  it be `spain+luffy` or `spain+usopp`? Why? It is not **determined** in the query how to choose "better" **wmname** if several are suitable, so the result is also not determined. That's why SQL interpreter returns an error - the query is not correct.

In the other word, there is no correct answer to the question *"Who is the best in `spain` group?"*. Luffy is not better than usopp, because usopp has the same "score".

Comment: This solution worked for me too. I had query problems because my ORM also included the associated primary key, resulting in the following _incorrect_ query: `SELECT cname, id, MAX(avg) FROM makerar GROUP BY cname;`, which did give this misleading error.

Answer (score 21):

```
SELECT t1.cname, t1.wmname, t2.max
FROM makerar t1 JOIN (
    SELECT cname, MAX(avg) max
    FROM makerar
    GROUP BY cname ) t2
ON t1.cname = t2.cname AND t1.avg = t2.max;
```

Using `rank()` [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html):

```
SELECT cname, wmname, avg
FROM (
    SELECT cname, wmname, avg, rank() 
    OVER (PARTITION BY cname ORDER BY avg DESC)
    FROM makerar) t
WHERE rank = 1;
```

**Note**

Either one will preserve multiple max values per group. If you want only single record per group even if there is more than one record with avg equal to max you should check @ypercube's answer.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work as well

```
SELECT *
FROM makerar m1
WHERE m1.avg = (SELECT MAX(avg)
                FROM makerar m2
                WHERE m1.cname = m2.cname
               )
```

Answer (score -1):

I recently run into this problem, when trying to count using `case when`, and found that changing the order of the `which` and `count` statements fixes the problem:

```
SELECT date(dateday) as pick_day,
COUNT(CASE WHEN (apples = 'TRUE' OR oranges 'TRUE') THEN fruit END)  AS fruit_counter

FROM pickings

GROUP BY 1
```

Instead of using - in the latter, where I got errors that apples and oranges should appear in aggregate functions

```
CASE WHEN ((apples = 'TRUE' OR oranges 'TRUE') THEN COUNT(*) END) END AS fruit_counter
```

Comment: The `which` statement?