# Sequelize select with aggregate includes bad attributes => error

Tags: orm, inner-join, sequelize.js

The models are `Person` and `Team` with a M:1 relationship.

The query that fails:

```
db.Person.findAll({
    attributes: [ [sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('*')), 'count']],
    include: [{model: db.Team, required: true}], // to force inner join
    group: ['team.team_id']
    }).complete(function(err, data) {
        ...
    });
```

The generated SQL is:

```
SELECT "person"."person_id", 
       COUNT(*) AS "count", 
       "team"."team_id" AS "team.team_id", 
       "team"."team_name" AS "team.team_name", 
       "team"."team_email" AS "team.team_email",
       "team"."team_lead" AS "team.team_lead" 
FROM "person" AS "person" INNER JOIN "team" AS "team" 
    ON "person"."team_id" = "team"."team_id" 
GROUP BY "team"."team_id";
```

Obviously, the `person.person_id` included in the `SELECT` clause, screws it up, with Postgres complaining correctly that:

```
ERROR:  column "person.person_id" must appear in the `GROUP BY` clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

It seems that the `attributes` option is taken into account since the `COUNT` appears correctly, but all the rest of the columns in the `SELECT` clause are added by default.

Is there another way (besides `attributes`) to explicitly define which columns appear in the `SELECT` clause or is this a bug?

I'm using Sequelize v2.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize will always add the primary key to the selected fields. Currently there is no way to disable that.

Perhaps adding `DISTINCT ON` as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19723716/800016 to `person_id` could fix the issue?

Otherwise, feel free to open an issue on the sequelize bug tracker

Comment: Its been couple of years since this answer, Is it still true that "Sequelize will always add the primary key to the selected fields", and that there is no work around?