# ERROR: column "this_.created_time" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate

I encountered a problem when I did a query with hibernate's criteria. The generated SQL is very simple:

```
/* criteria query */ 
select
    count(*) as y0_ 
from
    cx_vss_video this_ 
where
    this_.uploader_id=? 
order by
    this_.created_time asc
```

And it complained the error:

```
    Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "this_.created_time" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
  Position: 105
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2157)
```

There was a existed samilar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601948/must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause-or-be-used-in-an-aggregate-function). But its answer seems very complicated and not resonable. So any another solution?

My entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cx_vss_video")
public class Video {

    public enum TranscodingStatus {
      NOT_START, TRANSCODING, SUCCESS, ERROR, CANCELED;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "cx_vss_video_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "cx_vss_video_seq", sequenceName = "cx_vss_video_seq")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "uploader_name", nullable = false)
    private String uploaderName;

    @Column(name = "file_name")
    @NaturalId
    private String fileName;

    @Column(name = "created_time")
    private Date createdTime = new Date();

    @Column(name = "transcoding_status")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TranscodingStatus transcodingStatus = TranscodingStatus.TRANSCODING;
}
```

I can order by `file_name` normaly but no luck when ordered by `created_time`. I'm confused where does the problem come about? And the problem also arise when I using H2.

**EDIT**
I finally solved the problem by removing the order argument and it works now.

```
CriteriaImpl criteriaImpl = criteria instanceof CriteriaImpl ? (CriteriaImpl) criteria : null;
  if (criteriaImpl != null) {
    Iterator<OrderEntry> it = criteriaImpl.iterateOrderings();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
      it.next();
      it.remove();
    }
    criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
    totalResults = (long) criteria.uniqueResult();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an aggregation function on the query.  So, it should look like this:

```
select count(*) as y0_ 
from cx_vss_video this_ 
where this_.uploader_id = ? 
group by ??
order by max(this_.created_time) asc;
```

That is, you need a `group by` and to fix the `order by`.

Why?  Well, your original query -- without the `group by` -- is an aggregation query that returns one row.  It doesn't make sense to order a result set with one row.  So, I assume you want to aggregate by something, hence the `??`.  Then, you can order by either an aggregation column or an aggregation function.