# Order by subquery with Spring JPA Specification

Tags: java, spring, jpa, specifications

I have a problem with sorting, which would have been easily solved by native SQL and probably JPQL, but not Spring JPA Specifications.

Here is the trimmed domain model:

```
@Entity
class DesignElement {
   List<Change> changes;
}
@Entity
class Change {
   List<DesignElement> designElements;
}
@Entity
class Vote {
   Change change;
   VoteType type;
}
```

Users publish their `Change` proposals on several elements, and other users vote these changes with `VoteType` of `GREAT`, `GOOD`, `NEUTRAL` or `BAD`.

What I try to accomplish is to order `Entity`s (not `Change`s) by the count of `GOOD` and `GREAT` votes.

It might have been easier with SQL or JPQL but we try to utilize `Specification` API since we need several other predicates and orders.

After two days of agony I have come up with several assumptions about what I cannot do with Specification api. Some of them are probably wrong, if so I will edit the question with answers.

- We cannot just add `count(Vote_.id)` in the root query if we have several `Specification<DesignElement>`s to be combined.
- It is not possible to order by subquery in JPA: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-256
- It is not possible to do a `multiselect` in subquery.

Here are several other working `Order`s defined inside other `Specification<DesignElement>`s:

```
private static void appendOrder(CriteriaQuery<?> query, Order order) {
    List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>(query.getOrderList());
    orders.add(0, order);
    query.orderBy(orders);
}

public static Specification<DesignElement> orderByOpen() {
    return new Specification<DesignElement>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<DesignElement> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
            appendOrder(query, cb.desc(root.get("status").get("open")));
            return null;
        }
    };
}

public static Specification<DesignElement> orderByReverseSeverityRank() {
    return new Specification<DesignElement>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<DesignElement> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
            appendOrder(query, cb.desc(root.get("severity").get("rank")));
            return null;
        }
    };
}

public static Specification<DesignElement> orderByCreationTime() {
    return new Specification<DesignElement>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<DesignElement> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
            appendOrder(query, cb.asc(root.get("creationTime"));
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

Which would allow a usage like that:

```
List<DesignElement> elements = designElementDao.findAll(Specifications.where(orderByReverseSeverityRank()).and(orderByCreationTime());
```

Comment: I am trying to utilize Spring JPA Specification API: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/Specification.html

Answer (score 4):

I was facing same problem. For sorting by count(child-collection) I found a workaround - it's not ideal (polluting entity objects, not dynamic etc.), but for some cases, it might be enough.

1. define read-only field 'upvotesCount' holding the information to be used for sort

   ```
   @Entity
   class Change {

       List<DesignElement> designElements;

       // let's define read-only field, mapped to db view 
       @Column(table = "change_votes_view", name = "upvotes_count", updatable = false, insertable = false)
       Integer upvotesCount;

   }
   ```
2. implement db view which where the field is mapped to

   ```
   CREATE VIEW change_votes_view AS SELECT c.id, count(v.*) as upvotes_count
   FROM change c
   LEFT JOIN votes v 
     ON <ids-condition> AND <votes-are-up=condition>
   ```

Another way would be to go with DTO objects - you construct query which fits your needs and you can do it also dynamically.

Comment: Yes, `view`s are almost always applicable to situations like this but we are trying to avoid them.

Comment: still need to add `@SecondaryTable(name = "change_votes_view")` to entity

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with somewhat hacky solution.

There was another problem which was not apparent in the H2 unit test DB, but showed up on the actual Postgres installation: You have to group by a column if it is directly used inside an `Order by` clause: [must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601948/must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause-or-be-used-in-an-aggregate-function)

The solution involves around two different approaches:

- Construct the joins so that there won't be duplicate rows **and** just do an identity aggregate operation (like `sum`) on these single rows

*Or*

- Construct the joins with interested duplicate rows **and** `count` the number of child id's. (And don't forget to `group by` root `id`).

Counting the number of child id's was the way to go for this problem. But even that (creating a precondition on the interested rows) proved difficult (I am pretty sure it is possible) so I took a somewhat hacky approach: cross join all the children, and do a `sum` on `case`:

```
public static Specification<DesignElement> orderByGoodVotes() {
    return new Specification<DesignElement>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<DesignElement> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {

            ListAttribute<? super DesignElement, Alert> designElementChanges = root.getModel().getList("changes", Change.class);
            ListJoin<Change, Vote> changeVotes = root.join(designElementChanges).joinList("votes", JoinType.LEFT);
            Path<VoteType> voteType = changeVotes.get("type");

            // This could have been avoided with a precondition on Change -> Vote join
            Expression<Integer> goodVotes1_others0 = cb.<Integer>selectCase().when(cb.in(voteType).value(GOOD).value(GREAT, 1).otherwise(0);

            Order order = cb.desc(cb.sum(goodVotes1_others0));
            appendOrder(query, order);

            // This is required
            query.groupBy(root.get("id"));
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

I generalized this approach and fixed the previous specifications:

```
public static Specification<DesignElement> orderByOpen() {
    return new Specification<DesignElement>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<DesignElement> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
            Expression<Integer> opens1_others0 = cb.<Integer>selectCase().when(cb.equal(root.get("status").get("open"), Boolean.TRUE), 1).otherwise(0);
            appendOrder(query, cb.desc(cb.sum(opens1_others0)));
            query.groupBy(root.get("id"));
            return null;
        }
    };
}

public static Specification<DesignElement> orderByReverseSeverityRank() {
    return new Specification<DesignElement>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<DesignElement> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
            appendOrder(query, cb.asc(cb.sum(root.get("severity").get("rank"))));
            query.groupBy(root.get("id"));
            return null;
        }
    };
}

public static Specification<DesignElement> orderByCreationTime() {
    return new Specification<DesignElement>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<DesignElement> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
            // This isn't changed, we are already selecting all the root attributes
            appendOrder(query, cb.desc(root.get("creationTime")));
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

Since there are ~15 other `Specification`s like these, I guess there will be a performance penalty for being so lazy but I did not analyze it.