# Python & PostgreSQL problem with GROUP BY

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I have got some problems with function view(). I received error:

> column "store.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an   aggregate functio

For instance:

```
name    number       quantity
plc        55              1
engine     66              1
plc        55              3
```

OUTPUT:

```
name    number       quantity
plc        55              4
engine     66              1
```

Comment: This is sort of a fundamental misunderstanding of aggregation in SQL queries.  But to help, we need to know what you want your output to look like.  For example, when using `GROUP BY` the results will be one record per group -- but there may be many table rows that "fall into" that group.  How do you want them displayed?  (Consider `id`, there may be many `id`s that all match your criteria and end up in the same group -- do you want them all combined into one "cell"?)

Comment: I' ve updated my post to clarify my problem.

Comment: re: your update: `SELECT name, number, SUM(quantity)` and group by the columns that you aren't aggregating (which are name and number) -- so `GROUP BY name, number`.  Selecting anything else will require you to either add it to the list in `GROUP BY` or aggregate it (as you with `SUM(quantity)`).

Comment: Is any chance to received also an ID without grouping by it?

Answer (score 2):

I imagine that you are looking for something like this:

```sql
SELECT
  name,
  producent,
  model,
  number,
  SUM(quantity),
  warehouse,
  location
FROM store
WHERE
  quantity > 0
GROUP BY
  name,
  producent,
  model,
  number,
  warehouse,
  location
ORDER BY
  number;
```

I removed `id` from the selected fields, since you are already declaring that as a `UNIQUE` (`PRIMARY KEY`) field in the `CREATE TABLE` statement earlier (becauase it is autoincremented by the sequence you are declaring). You never want to group on a `UNIQUE` field - it will just give you the same results as without it.

But in order to be certain, we need to know what you want your output to look like.

A rule of thumb here, when it comes to grouping results with SQL is this: Always include all the fields that are selected outside of an aggregate function in the `GROUP BY` clause.

## **Update**

You have edited your question, so that the original query you included is gone. But it looks like you have included the results that you want instead. Here's how you would get those:

```sql
SELECT
  name,
  number,
  SUM(quantity) as "quantity"
FROM store
WHERE
  quantity > 0
GROUP BY
  name,
  number
ORDER BY
  number;
```

I hope you can accept the answer like this.

Comment: Hi! I hope the answer was helpful. Please let me know if there is something else I can help with in respect to this - or perhaps accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

change your query like below

```
SELECT  name,  number,
 SUM(quantity) FROM store WHERE quantity>0 
 GROUP BY name,  number  ORDER BY number
```

you have to put non aggregated selected column into `group by` also

Comment: I'm not sure what the point of grouping is if you're going to include the primary key in the list of grouped-by columns...

Comment: @jedwards answer edited as you edited your question i mentioned that you have to put column name in group by those are selected but non aggregated

Answer (score 0):

By default the columns in select are expected in group by clause.
You can include all the columns in select also in group by as mentioned above.
I also see an alternative where a `sub query` can be used to avoid including all columns in group by. 
Please refer this link-
[previous answer for related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601948/must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause-or-be-used-in-an-aggregate-function)