# MYSQL - groupby funtion not working in 5.7

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have created table :

```
CREATE TABLE `testForGroupBy` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `empId` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Data insetrted :

[image]

when I query,

```
select * from (select * from testForGroupBy order by empId desc)a group by name;
```

[image]

Expeceted :

[image]

I googled and found that 5.7 will not work for the partial groupby to make it works need to change `sql_mode` like below and restarted,

```
STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

But still the same result!

Where am I doing a mistake ?

Comment: The change to sql_mode is for getting rid of an error message. If you got results, it has nothing to do with that.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya He didn't get an error, he got unexpected results.

Comment: I have done the configuration as said in the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column but still i didnt get the exact OP

Comment: Can there be duplicate `empId` for the same `name`?

Comment: @Barmar No error, Mysql restarted successfully. but same OP!?

Comment: @trincot the same query working perfectly in 5.6 version of my production environment.

Comment: @MMMMS If it worked, it was just by accident, it was never guaranteed. See the duplicate question for the correct way to do it.

Comment: That was not my question :) Anyway this question has been closed. You'll find the explanation and suggestions in the linked Q&A to make your query valid by SQL standards (which MySql threw out the window in past versions)

Answer (score -4):

I found out about this type of what I would name unpredictable behavior when I started to work with `Postgres` and I got the error [*must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601948/must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause-or-be-used-in-an-aggregate-function).

A solution for you would be to rewrite the query like:

```
select id, name, MAX(empId) from testForGroupBy group by name;
```

Please not that the value for `id` would also be "unpredictable" for the grouped records.

Comment: That won't return the correct `id` value.

Comment: what would be the *correct* `id` value in this case? That's exactly why I mentioned `Postgres`'s behavior before writing the query and I mentioned again that `id` is *unpredictable*, aka *not always correct*

Comment: From his desired output, it looks like he wants the id to be correct. Since there's an easy way to get that result, why would you post this? See the duplicate question if you aren't familiar with it, it should be in every MySQL programmer's bag of tricks.