# Adding row value after grouping the table causes * must appear in the GROUP BY clause

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I am trying to join 2 tables like so:

```
left join (
    select t1.createdate, min(f1.createdate) as mindt, f1.status_aft
    from new_table t1
    left join new_folder f1 on t1.veh_id = f1.veh_id
    where f1.createdate > t1.createdate
    group by t1.createdate
) h3
on t1.createdate = h3.createdate
and f1.createdate = h3.mindt
```

But I am getting an error:

> ERROR:  column "f1.status_aft" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an   aggregate function

This makes sense because I do not group it, my goal is just to take the value that is in that current row when `f1.createdate` is `min`.

For example:

```
A       B       C
one     10      a
one     15      b
two     20      c
two     25      d
```

Becomes

```
A       B       C
one     10      a
two     20      c
```

Because `a` and `c` was the values when column `B` were the lowest after grouping it by column `A`.

I've [seen this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601948/must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause-or-be-used-in-an-aggregate-function) but I still can't apply it to my scenario.

How can I achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

> my goal is just to take the value that is in that current row when f1.createdate is min.

If you want just one row, you can order by and limit:

```
left join (
    select t1.t1.createdate, f1.createdate as mindt, f1.status_aft
    from new_table t1
    left join new_folder f1 on t1.veh_id = f1.veh_id
    where f1.createdate > t1.createdate
    order by t1.createdate limit 1
) h3
```

Comment: Thanks, but that does not work for me, I get duplicated rows and `null` values in that column. Do you have an idea what might cause this?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis: the subquery is guaranteed to return just one row (or no row at all), so this cannot duplicate rows. You only showed one small part of the query, so I cannot comment on how to solve the issue you describe here...