# How can I GROUP BY a single column in SQL?

Tags: postgresql

This is the rather basic query I tried:

```
SELECT cust_id, prod_id, total_amount as total_revenue
FROM sales
GROUP BY prod_id;
```

Trying to make an output like this:

```
 cust_id | prod_id | total_revenue
---------+---------+--------------
 1       | 1       |        574.32
 1       | 2       |         78.09
 1       | 3       |          8.48
 2       | 1       |        706.11
 2       | 2       |        104.03
 2       | 3       |         58.01
```

But I get,

```
ERROR:  column "sales.cust_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

If I add all columns to GROUP BY, the output looks like this:

```
 cust_id | prod_id | total_revenue 
---------+---------+------------
 1       | 1       |        2.11
 1       | 1       |        0.80
 2       | 1       |        2.50
 1       | 1       |        3.13
 2       | 1       |        1.55
 1       | 1       |        0.75
 1       | 1       |        2.03
```

...
(405 rows)

[Here the top answer that says this is a 'common aggregation problem'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601948/must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause-or-be-used-in-an-aggregate-function) but I haven't been able to implement it.

[This solution talks about an optimizer.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/88988/postgres-error-column-must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause-or-be-used-in-an-aggre)

Yet another fix uses "With cte" and gives a long solution but this seems like this should be a simple query. Thanks for reading.

Comment: `SELECT cust_id, prod_id, sum(total_amount) as total_revenue from sales GROUP BY cust_id, prod_id`

Comment: Yes, the GROUP BY statement is used with aggregate functions.  Such as the example of @JonathanWillcock.

Comment: This worked, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is due to the nature of the **`GROUP BY`** statement, when you use it you need to group all the fields that aren't part of the aggregate function (sum, max, min, etc) + one or more aggregate functions.

```sql
SELECT prod_id , cust_id, sum(total_amount) as total_revenue
FROM sales
GROUP BY prod_id, cust_id;
```

Comment: Thanks, that gave the output I wanted when I added cust_id to the GROUP BY clause. Then I could drop the MAX() but it seemed to work both ways.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT prod_id , cust_id, sum(total_amount) as total_revenue
FROM sales
GROUP BY 1,2;
```