# Counting in Many-To-Many Relations Sequelize

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to count number of Followers and Followings of a user.
as `followingCount` and `followerCount`

`User Model`

```js
User.init(
    {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      },
      email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
      },
      password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
      },
    }
  );

static associate(models) {
      // Follow relationship
      this.belongsToMany(models.User, {
        through: 'UserFollow',
        foreignKey: 'followerId',
        as: 'following',
      });

      // Follow relationship
      this.belongsToMany(models.User, {
        through: 'UserFollow',
        foreignKey: 'followeeId',
        as: 'follower',
      });
    }
```

Where `UserFollow` is a Joint Table with columns `followeeId` and `followerId`.

My current approach for finding number of followings is something like this :

```js
const user = await User.findOne({
      where: {
        id,
      },
      attributes: [
        'id',
        'userName',
        'email',
        [sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('following->UserFollow.followeeId')), 'followingCount'],
      ],
      include: [
        {
          model: User,
          as: 'following',
          attributes: ['id', 'userName', 'email'],
          through: {
            attributes: [],
          },
        },
      ],
      group: ['User.id', 'following.id'],
    });

    return user;
```

And Output getting is like this:

Here I am getting `followingCount` as `1`... but it should be `3`.

```json
"data": {
        "id": "1af4b9ea-7c58-486f-a37a-e46461487b06",
        "userName": "xyz",
        "email": "xyz@gmail.com",
        "followingCount": "1",         <------ I want this to be 3
        "following": [
            {
                "id": "484202b0-a6d9-416d-a8e2-6681deffa3d1",
                "userName": "uqwheuo",
                "email": "uqwheuo@gmail.com"
            },
            {
                "id": "56c8d9b0-f5c6-4b2e-b32c-be6363294614",
                "userName": "aiwhroanc",
                "email": "aiwhroanc@gmail.com"
            },
            {
                "id": "9a3e4074-c7a0-414e-8df4-cf448fbaf5fe",
                "userName": "iehaocja",
                "email": "iehaocja@gmail.com"
            }
        ]
    }
```

I am not able to count in Joint Table..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that you are getting `followingCount: 1` is that you group by `following.id` (`followeeId`). It only counts unique `followeeId` which is always 1.

Although, if you take out `following.id` from `group`, the SQL doesn't work any more. It will crash with "a column must appear in GROUP BY clause...". This is a common issue in Postgres and this link (https://stackoverflow.com/a/19602031/2956135) explains the topic well in detail.

To solve your question, instead of using `group`, you can use `COUNT OVER (PARTITION BY)`.

```
const user = await User.findOne({
  where: {
    id,
  },
  attributes: [
    'id',
    'userName',
    'email',
    [Sequelize.literal('COUNT("following->UserFollow"."followeeId") OVER (PARTITION BY "User"."id")'), 'followingCount']
  ],
  include: [
    {
      model: User,
      as: 'following',
      attributes: ['id', 'userName', 'email'],
      through: {
        attributes: [],
      }
    },
  ],
});
```

======================================================

Update:

The original query only fetch "following" relationship. In order to fetch followers of this user, you first need to add "follower" association.

Then, since 2 associations is added, we need to add 1 more partition by column to count exactly the `followers` or `followees`.

```
const followeeIdCol = '"following->UserFollow"."followeeId"';
const followerIdCol = '"follower->UserFollow"."followerId"';

const user = await User.findOne({
  where: {
    id,
  },
  attributes: [
    'id',
    'userName',
    'email',
    // Note that the COUNT column and partition by column is reversed.
    [Sequelize.literal(`COUNT(${followeeIdCol}) OVER (PARTITION BY "Users"."id", ${followerIdCol})`), 'followingCount'],
    [Sequelize.literal(`COUNT(${followerIdCol}) OVER (PARTITION BY "Users"."id", ${followeeIdCol})`), 'followerCount'],
  ],
  include: [
    {
      model: User,
      as: 'following',
      attributes: ['id', 'userName', 'email'],
      through: {
        attributes: [],
      }
    },
    {
      model: User,
      as: 'follower',       // Add follower association
      attributes: ['id', 'userName', 'email'],
      through: {
        attributes: [],
      }
    },
  ],
});
```

Comment: Yeah this method works. But what if I have to get both `followers` and `followings` ? 
adding two `[Sequelize.literal()]....` statement for both followers and followings doesn't seem to give proper values.... one gives correct and another gives incorrect

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: I am having same problem with `"PostLikes"` join table... where it contains `userId` and `postId`... aliasing `likes` to both field in association..
I want to count number of likes on some post with all the liked users and other post details.... here is query just for count...
```[sequelize.literal(`COUNT("likes->PostLikes"."postId") OVER (PARTITION BY "likes->PostLikes"."userId")`), 'likesCount'],``` not giving required output..

Comment: it is hard to say without seeing the model definitions and associations.  If you still have the issue, you can post the new question.

Comment: I have posted the question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70781543/count-in-many-to-many-relationship-sequelize