# Count in Many-to-Many relationship

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I want to count the number of likes when I fetch the post details.

`User Model`

```js
User.init(
    {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      },
      userName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
        field: 'user_name',
      },
    }
  );
static associate(models) {
      // User has many posts --> One-to-Many Relationship
      this.hasMany(models.Post, {
        foreignKey: 'userId',
      });

      // Likes relationship
      this.belongsToMany(models.Post, {
        through: 'PostLikes',
        foreignKey: 'userId',
        as: 'likes',
      });
    }
```

And here is the `Post Model`

```js
Post.init(
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      },
      body: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    }
  );
static associate(models) {
      // User-Post Relationship
      this.belongsTo(models.User, {
        foreignKey: 'userId',
      });

      // Likes Relationship
      this.belongsToMany(models.User, {
        through: 'PostLikes',
        foreignKey: 'postId',
        as: 'likes',
      });
    }
```

So, it now creates a joined table `PostLikes` and I am trying query that fetches the post along with the likes and number of likes on that post.

```js
const postsIdCol = '"likes->PostLikes"."postId"';
const usersIdCol = '"likes->PostLikes"."userId"';
const postCol = '"Post"."id"';

const response = await Post.findOne({
      where: {
        id: postid,
      },
      // includeIgnoreAttributes : false,
      attributes: [
        'id', 'body', 'createdAt', 
        [sequelize.literal(`COUNT(${postsIdCol}) OVER (PARTITION BY ${postCol})`), 'likesCount'],
      ],
      include: [
        {                               
          model: Comment,          ----> Post is also associated with comments, ignore this
          as: 'comments',
          attributes: ['id', 'content', 'createdAt', 'updatedAt'],
        },
        {
          model: User,
          as: 'likes',
          through: {
            attributes: [],
          },
          attributes: ['id', 'userName'],
        },
      ],
    });

    return response;
```

The Response I am getting on doing this query is like this :

```js
{
    "data": {
        "id": "182d6377-5bf6-4b65-9e29-cb79acc85c0a",
        "body": "hoping for the best",
        "likesCount": "6",                -----> this should be 3
        "likes": [
            {
                "id": "1af4b9ea-7c58-486f-a37a-e46461487b06",
                "userName": "sdfbsd",
            },
            {
                "id": "484202b0-a6d9-416d-a8e2-6681deffa3d1",
                "userName": "ndnadonfsu",
            },
            {
                "id": "b3c70bee-e839-4449-b213-62813af031d1",
                "userName": "difniandca",
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I can guess that for this post you have two comments. Am I right?

Comment: Yess. there can be any number of comments though.. I am least worried about comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another PARTITION BY column from the other association than the one that you want to count.

For example, if you want to count the likes, you need to partition by parent id (Post.id) and other association id (Comment.id).

If you want to count the comments, you need to partition by parent id (Post.id) and other association id ("likes->PostLikes"."UserId").

```js
[Sequelize.literal(`COUNT(${postsIdCol}) OVER (PARTITION BY ${postCol}, "Comments"."id")`), 'likesCount']
```

Where it says "Comments", you need to add your comment table name.