# Get the latest entry of each duplicate on Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using Postgres v12, and I have a table with duplicated rows. I need to retrieve only the last entry for each duplicate, ignoring entries which have no duplicate.

This table has the following columns:

- id (unique)
- request_id (where to find the duplicates)
- created_at (where to see which entry is the latest)

| id | request_id | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 2020.06.06 |
| 2 | a | 2020.05.05 |
| 3 | b | 2020.04.04 |
| 4 | b | 2020.03.03 |
| 5 | c | 2020.04.04 |
| 6 | c | 2020.03.03 |
| 7 | d | 2020.03.03 |

The query should retrieve rows with id 1,3,5 , since they are the latest entry (created_at) of each duplicate. ID 7 has no duplicate, so it is ignored.

I have tried with the solution proposed here: https://www.geeksengine.com/article/get-single-record-from-duplicates.html but due to be using Postgres v12, those queries do not work, I get the error "column must appear in the group by clause" which is another problem cited here: [must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601948/must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause-or-be-used-in-an-aggregate-function)

I have been searching for a solution for days to this problem, but I am not an SQL expert. I would appreciate any help very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is one way using window functions :

```
select * from (
    select * 
        , row_number() over (partition by request_id order by created_at desc) as rn
        , count() over (partition by request_id) cn 
    from tablename
) t where cn > 1 and rn = 1
```

Comment: Awesome. I have been looking for a solution for days. This works perfectly!