# Aggregate multiple detail rows in a join query

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, aggregation

I have a couple of tables where I'm applying inner join to fetch matching rows:

```
event (id, url, name, eventStart, eventEnd)`  
slot (id, event_id date, start_time, end_time,
    location_type, location_id)`
```

Query:

```
select * from event as evnt 
inner join slot as slot on evnt.id = slot.event_id
where location_type = 'type of location' and slot.location_id = '12345'
and slot.event_id = :eventId
```

This works fine. But sometimes a single event may have multiple slots. The result would be multiple rows for the same event. All column values in `slot` are the same for the same event, except `date, start_time, end_time`. I tried aggregating slot values like below, and this works fine:

```
select event_id,
    array_agg(concat(date,':',start_time,':',end_time)) as slotDates
from slot
where event_id = 'event id' and location_id = '12345' 
group by event_id
```

When I join to the main query, it gives me an error:

```
select event_id,
    array_agg(concat(date,':',start_time,':',end_time)) as slotDates,
    evnt.id as eventId, evnt.url as eventUrl,
    evnt.name as eventName, evnt.event_start as eventStart,
    evnt.event_end as eventEnd, slot.location_type as locationType  
from event as evnt 
inner join slot as slot on evnt.id = slot.event_id
where slot.location_type = 'type of location'
and slot.location_id = '12345'
and slot.event_id = 'event id goes here'
group by slot.event_id
```

> `ERROR:  column "evnt.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

How to fix this?

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask about 1 bad query/function with the obligatory [mre] & why you think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect justified by reference to authoritative documentation or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about the former 1st because misconceptions in the former will get in the way of understanding the latter. And bad code doesn't tell us what you wish it would do. [ask] [Help]

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Comment: Duplicate of [must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19601948/3404097)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Schema (PostgreSQL v14)**

```
CREATE TABLE event(
id integer,
url text,
name text, 
event_start  date, 
event_end   date
);

CREATE TABLE slot(
id integer,
event_id integer,
date date,
start_time  date, 
end_time   date,
location_type text, 
location_id integer
);

INSERT INTO event(id, url, name, event_start, event_end) VALUES(1, 'URL', 'NAME', CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_DATE);

INSERT INTO slot(id, event_id,date, end_time, start_time, location_type, location_id) VALUES(1, 1, CURRENT_DATE + 1, CURRENT_DATE + 2, CURRENT_DATE + 3, 'type of location', 12345);

INSERT INTO slot(id, event_id,date, end_time, start_time, location_type, location_id) VALUES(2, 1, CURRENT_DATE + 4, CURRENT_DATE + 5, CURRENT_DATE + 6, 'type of location', 12345);
```

---

**Query**

```
select 
    evnt.id as eventId, 
    evnt.url as eventUrl, 
    evnt.name as eventName, 
    evnt.event_start as eventStart, 
    evnt.event_end as eventEnd,
    agg_slot.slotDates, 
    agg_slot.location_type
from event as evnt,
     (select event_id, 
             location_type,
             location_id,
             array_agg(concat(slot.date,':',slot.start_time,':',slot.end_time)) as slotDates 
       from slot as slot       
       group by event_id, location_id, location_type ) as agg_slot
where evnt.id = agg_slot.event_id and evnt.id = 1
and agg_slot.location_type = 'type of location' and agg_slot.location_id = '12345';
```

| eventid | eventurl | eventname | eventstart | eventend | slotdates | location_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | URL | NAME | 2022-08-22T00:00:00.000Z | 2022-08-22T00:00:00.000Z | 2022-08-23:2022-08-25:2022-08-24,2022-08-26:2022-08-28:2022-08-27 | type of location |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wPiaXKfesiJzAA72u14DLy/2)

**Or in case you need to get only one single aggregated column**

```
select 
    evnt.id as eventId, 
    evnt.url as eventUrl, 
    evnt.name as eventName, 
    evnt.event_start as eventStart, 
    evnt.event_end as eventEnd,    
    (select array_agg(concat(slot.date,':',slot.start_time,':',slot.end_time))
       from slot as slot
       where slot.event_id = evnt.id and  slot.location_id = '12345' and slot.location_type = 'type of location'
       group by event_id) as slotdates    
from event as evnt
where  evnt.id = 1;
```

| eventid | eventurl | eventname | eventstart | eventend | slotdates |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | URL | NAME | 2022-08-22T00:00:00.000Z | 2022-08-22T00:00:00.000Z | 2022-08-23:2022-08-25:2022-08-24,2022-08-26:2022-08-28:2022-08-27 |

---

Answer (score 2):

I suggest a `LATERAL` subquery:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   event e
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT min(s.location_type) AS locationtype
        , array_agg(concat_ws(':', date, start_time, end_time)) AS slotdates
   FROM   slot s
   WHERE  s.location_type = 'type of location'  -- slot filters here
   AND    s.location_id = 12345
   AND    s.event_id = e.id
   ) s ON true
WHERE  e.id = 1;  -- event id goes here
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=555dcbf52f7f05b72a99a44edc1e7bee)*

This *always* returns the event if its `id` exists. If there are no qualifying slots, `locationtype` and `slotdates` are NULL. That's typically more practical.

If you don't want the event without slots, use `CROOS JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` (and drop `ON true`). See:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

Either way, the point is to join **after** aggregating details, so we have no `GROUP BY` in the outer `SELECT` to begin with, thereby avoiding your original problem - in cheaper fashion.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurred because many fields you used in the `SELECT` clause did not appear in the `GROUP BY` clause. It is required because if a group has more than one row, it will not know which to keep and which to drop.
One easy solution is to put everything in the `GROUP BY` clause. But I am totally against it. You can get relevant information by conducting a self-join.

```sql
-- Modify the SELECT clause to get what you want
select *
from
(
    select event_id, array_agg(concat(date,':',start_time,':',end_time)) as slotDates 
    from slot 
    -- where event_id = 'event id' and location_id = '12345'
    -- Warning that WHERE clause will be processed before GROUP BY
    -- Consider add/remove the WHERE clause here based on your requirement
    group by event_id 
) as slotdates
join event on slotdates.event_id = event.id
join slot on event.id = slot.event_id
where event_id = 'event id' and location_id = '12345'
```

Comment: I tried this query, but seems I'm not getting the result in a single row. Did you try running this?

Comment: No, I can't run because I don't have the data. Did you configure the last WHERE clause correctly?

Comment: Yes, Where clause has been constructed correctly. Where slot.event_id = eventid and slot.location_id = locationid... Bcos these two columns exists only in slot table