# Find average salary of employees for each department and order employees within a department by age

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
    NAME VARCHAR(500) UNIQUE,
    AGE INT,
    DEPT VARCHAR(500),
    SALARY INT
)

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE  VALUES('RAMESH',20,'FINANCE',50000);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE  VALUES('DEEP',25,'SALES',30000);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE  VALUES('SURESH',22,'FINANCE',50000);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE  VALUES('RAM',28,'FINANCE',20000);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE  VALUES('PRADEEP',22,'SALES',20000);
```

Could someone explain the error in the query

```
SELECT NAME, AGE, DEPT, AVG(SALARY)
FROM EMPLOYEE
GROUP BY DEPT 
ORDER BY AGE
```

> (/* USING NAME,AGE ETC ALSO SHOWS ERROR- "column "employee.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function")

Why is there an error; consider both the logic part and the syntax part for explanation?

CAN ANYBODY PROVIDE THE ANSWER USING SUB QUERY?

Comment: What are you want to archive? an Avarege of dept salary?

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server <> PostgreSQL - please tag your *single* RDBMS.

Comment: The error is self explanatory... when grouping, the selected columns must either be grouped by or aggregated.

Comment: Please don't YELL at us (which is what ALL CAPITALS IS).

Comment: Put it this way, if you are `GROUP BY DEPT`, there will only one row per `DEPT`, so which name/age do you expect there to be in your output?

Comment: I removed the conflicting RDBMS tags... feel free to add the correct one back.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the error on at here : [must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601948/must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause-or-be-used-in-an-aggregate-function)
POSTGRESQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT NAME, AGE, DEPT
    , AVG(SALARY)
FROM EMPLOYEES
GROUP BY NAME, DEPT, AGE
ORDER BY AGE
```

Comment: You don't need `DISTINCT` if you are using `GROUP BY`.

Comment: But it will work perfectly without

Answer (score 0):

When you are using group by then you should extract only those columns which you used in group by and you can choose aggregate function with this. So you can use like below query.

```
select DEPT, AVG(SALARY) FROM EMPLOYEE GROUP BY DEPT
```