# use GROUP BY and ORDER BY with JPA repository on object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities:

Item:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item", schema = "public")
public class ItemEntity {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner", nullable = false)
    private UserEntity user;
    ....
}
```

ItemView:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item_view", schema = "public")
public class ItemViewEntity {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private UserEntity user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "item_id", nullable = false)
    private ItemEntity item;
}
```

I want to return Items of user in order of the amount time they were viewed of

```
public interface ItemViewRepository extends JpaRepository<ItemViewEntity, Long> {
   @Query("Select u.item from ItemViewEntity u WHERE u.item.owner= ?! group by u.item order by count(u.item") desc")
   List<ItemEntity> getItemsByViews(UserEntity user);
}
```

Using this query i get error"

`ERROR: column "itementi1_.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

I have all `equals` method defined on each entity

I have tried using group by and so on on primitive types and it all works. It seems i has problem with relations.

How can i fix this and make the query work?

Comment: the select query should contain the column name to be grouped by. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601948/must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause-or-be-used-in-an-aggregate-function

Comment: ` group by u.item` it does contain it

Comment: it should also use the aggregator function on that column COUNT(), MAX(), MIN(), SUM(), AVG()

Comment: there is also count(recipe)..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by explicitly specifying a join in your query

```
    @Query("SELECT i, COUNT(v) AS viewcount " +
            "FROM ItemViewEntity v " +
            "JOIN v.item i " +
            "WHERE i.user = ?1 " +
            "GROUP BY i " +
            "ORDER BY viewcount DESC")
    List<ItemEntity> getItemsByViews(UserEntity user);
```