# PostgreSQL GROUP BY Error "id must appear in the GROUP BY or be usedd in an aggregate function"

Tags: sql, postgresql

So, I have this kind of table:

[image: My table]

I want to Group the id_class, and count the id_student like this:

[image: Table that I wanted]

I used this query:

```
SELECT id, id_class, COUNT(id_student) FROM tbl_school_years GROUP BY id_class
```

but I got this error:

> Failed to run sql query: column "tbl_school_years.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Any solution? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Why in your expected output `id` in first row 1 and not let's say 2?

Comment: Please find a basic SQL tutorial. Proper use of SELECT with GROUP BY is basic SQL functionality, and learning the basics now will save you a lot of frustration going forward. Also,  please do a thorough search for the error message before asking a question, as chances are quite good that it has been asked about before here. SO should be your **last resort** after you've exhausted all other means of finding an answer yourself, and not doing a search is basic effort you should make.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601948/must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause-or-be-used-in-an-aggregate-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column `id` could not be in the select clause since it is not on `group by` clause

We need at first to get id_class and the total_student using :

```
SELECT id_class, COUNT(id_student) as total_student
FROM tbl_school_years 
GROUP BY id_class
```

Then we join this subquery with `tbl_school_years` to get all the possible ids, then using group by we get the smallest or the biggest id using `min` or `max` functions

```
with cte as (
  select t.id, s.*
  from tbl_school_years t
  inner join (
    SELECT id_class, COUNT(id_student) as total_student
    FROM tbl_school_years 
    GROUP BY id_class
  ) as s on s.id_class = t.id_class
)
select min(id), id_class, total_student
from cte
group by id_class, total_student
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/dgUoK20B)