# group by and order shows error GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, postgresql-16

I have a table `sub_table` like this:

| "id" | "created_datetime" | "main_table_id" | "skill" | ... | "team" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-11-01 01:00:00 | 1 | drum | ... | a |
| 2 | 2023-11-02 02:00:00 | 1 | guitar | ... | a |
| 3 | 2023-11-03 03:00:00 | 1 | vocal | ... | b |
| 4 | 2023-11-04 04:00:00 | 2 | bass | ... | b |

Goal 1:

- Base on where "main_table_id"
- Then group by "team" , order by "created_datetime" newest 1
- Return all column

```
group by main_table_id , and newest 1 group by team
[{
 "id": 2, "created_datetime": 2023-11-02 02:00:00, ...
}, {
 "id": 4, "created_datetime": 2023-11-04 04:00:00, ...
}]
```

Goal 2:

- Base on where "main_table_id"  and "team"
- Then group by "team" , order by "created_datetime"
- Return all column

```
main_table_id = 1, team = a
[{
 "id": 2, "created_datetime": 2023-11-02 02:00:00, ...
}, {
 "id": 1, "created_datetime": 2023-11-01 01:00:00, ...
}]
```

I tried something like below query:

```
SELECT * FROM [table] GROUP BY team WHERE main_table_id = $1 AND team = $2
```

Or:

```
SELECT t1.* 
  FROM (
  SELECT team 
  FROM sub_table 
  GROUP BY team ORDER created_datetime DESC LIMIT 1
) t0 JOIN sub_table t1 
ON t0.team = t1.team WHERE t1.main_table_id = $1 `;
```

Ref: answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19602031

Because I need to return all column, so all I tried about using `GROUP BY` will show error:

> must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: You show results for `main_table_id = 2, team = a`, but there are no matches in your example. Also, this seems to conflate two distinct queries / questions into one. Always disclose your version of Postgres. And an actual table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement) showing data types and constraints is the gold standard.

Comment: sry I made mistake, already edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Postgres, we can use `DISTINCT ON` here:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (team) id, created_datetime, main_table_id, skill
FROM sub_table
WHERE main_table_id = $1
ORDER BY team, created_datetime DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried this but get the error 'SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions', if I didnt put team after ORDER BY

Comment: Try the updated answer.

Comment: I dont get why if ORDER BY created_datetime DESC without team then it failed?

Comment: @user1775888: Because: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: You don't have to add `team`to the `SELECT` list. (But you can, of course.)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll make more pratice bout this ^^