# JdbcSQLException using GROUP BY on h2 Database

Tags: sql, h2

When I execute the following sql commands on an h2 database (version 1.3.161):

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
Name VARCHAR(10)
);

CREATE TABLE Actor
(
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
PersonId int,
FOREIGN KEY (PersonId) REFERENCES Person(Id)
);


INSERT INTO Person (name) values ('A person');

INSERT INTO Actor ( PERSONID ) values (1);
INSERT INTO Actor ( PERSONID ) values (1);

SELECT ACTOR.ID, ACTOR.PERSONID FROM ACTOR GROUP BY PERSONID ;
```

I the following exception:

```
    org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "ACTOR.ID" must be in the GROUP BY list; SQL statement:
SELECT ACTOR.ID, ACTOR.PERSONID FROM ACTOR GROUP BY PERSONID [90016-161]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146)
    at org.h2.expression.ExpressionColumn.updateAggregate(ExpressionColumn.java:155)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Select.queryGroupSorted(Select.java:183)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Select.queryWithoutCache(Select.java:610)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:298)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:268)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:37)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.query(CommandContainer.java:82)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeQuery(Command.java:185)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:173)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:152)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp.getResult(WebApp.java:1311)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp.query(WebApp.java:1001)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp$1.next(WebApp.java:964)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp$1.next(WebApp.java:967)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.process(WebThread.java:166)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.run(WebThread.java:93)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

If I execute exactly the same commands on a MYSQL DB it returns me the expected result:

```
 +----+----------+
 | id | PersonId |
 +----+----------+
 |  1 |        1 |
 +----+----------+
```

Comment: By the way you should upgrade the H2 database version. You are using version 1.3.161, which is very old (from 2011-10-28).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL is about the only database that allows this. I consider this a bug in MySQL. See also questions [Converting MySQL select to PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062158/converting-mysql-select-to-postgresql), [PostgreSQL GROUP BY different from MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769361/postgresql-group-by-different-from-mysql), [PostgreSQL -must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18061285/postgresql-must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause-or-be-used-in-an-aggregate-functi).

PostgreSQL throws the following exception:

```
ERROR: column "actor.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause 
or be used in an aggregate function 
42803/0
```

Apache Derby throws the following exception:

```
Column reference 'ACTOR.ID' is invalid, or is part of an invalid expression.  
For a SELECT list with a GROUP BY, the columns and expressions being selected 
may only contain valid grouping expressions and valid aggregate expressions. 
42Y36/30000
```

(I didn't test with other databases)