# Column I don't want to group => COLUMN must appear IN the GROUP BY clause OR be used IN an aggregate FUNCTION

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

I am getting this error, the query works in SQLite.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  COLUMN "receipts.is_read" must appear IN the GROUP BY clause OR be used IN an aggregate FUNCTION
```

Unsure what to do, it also occurs when I remove the coalesce part. I am not sure what else I can specify to make it work. Any ideas?

```
SELECT DISTINCT conversations.id, COALESCE(CASE WHEN receipts.is_read = 't' THEN 't' END, 'f') AS READ, conversations.updated_at, p1.nickname, p2.nickname
FROM conversations
INNER JOIN notifications ON notifications.conversation_id = conversations.id
INNER JOIN receipts ON receipts.notification_id = notifications.id
INNER JOIN profiles p1 ON p1.id = notifications.sender_id
INNER JOIN profiles p2 ON p2.id = receipts.receiver_id
WHERE (receipts.receiver_id = #{SELF.id} ) AND notifications.sender_id != #{SELF.id} OR (notifications.sender_id = #{SELF.id}) AND receipts.receiver_id != #{SELF.id}
GROUP BY conversations.id
ORDER BY conversations.updated_at DESC
```

Comment: Your version of Postgres?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL -must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18061285/postgresql-must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause-or-be-used-in-an-aggregate-functi)

Comment: Your query will probably work if you remove `group by conversation_id` or when you remove `distinct` and add all other field names in `select` clause to `group by`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an invalid mix of `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` and some un-grouped columns.
After replacing the mess with `DISTINCT ON` (and some other clean-up) this would work, but it's unclear, what you actually want to achieve:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (c.id)
       c.id, COALESCE(r.is_read, FALSE) AS read
     , c.updated_at, p1.nickname AS nickname1, p2.nickname AS nickname2
FROM   conversations c
JOIN   notifications n USING (conversation_id)
JOIN   receipts      r USING (notification_id)
JOIN   profiles      p1 ON p1.id = n.sender_id
JOIN   profiles      p2 ON p2.id = r.receiver_id
WHERE (r.receiver_id =  #{SELF.id} AND n.sender_id <> #{SELF.id} OR
       r.receiver_id <> #{SELF.id} AND n.sender_id =  #{SELF.id})
ORDER  BY c.id, c.updated_at DESC;
```

This gets you the row with the latest `conversations.updated_at` out of each group sharing the same `conversations.id`. Explanation:
[Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Comment: @bezzoon: Oh, `id` was missing in `ORDER BY`, sorry. Tested in 9.3. You did replace `#{SELF.id}` with an actual id, right? Also, assuming `is_read` is an actual `boolean` column for lack of information.

Comment: Brandlsetter  "is_read" boolean DEFAULT 'f -- , and i am using 9.3.4, I put schema data here! And yeah I am using an actual ID = ) !! https://gist.github.com/hassanshaikley/75c3d45bc3c77635324d

Comment: @bezzoon: Some clients don't accept duplicate column names. I added aliases.