# order by association's count of another model, limit to 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to display a gallery of magazines that shows the newest issue for each magazine title, but ordered by the number of subscriptions on that magazine.  I came up with this query

```
class IssuesController < ApplicationController
    def index
      @issues = Issue
        .includes(:magazine)
        .order('magazines.subscriptions_count DESC')
        .order(:release)
        .paginate(page: @page, per_page: 25)
    end
end
```

It correctly orders them by the suscriptions_count, however there are many entries for each magazine, each issue is displayed in order. I just want the first magazine for each one. I've tried adding `uniq` to the query, `group(:magazine_id)`, `limit(1)`, and more but I can't get it to only display one issue per magazine title.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails order by results count of has\_many association](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996618/rails-order-by-results-count-of-has-many-association)

Comment: No, this already has a counter cache applied, and I am getting the correct results already, just too many for each. I think I need to group them by `magazine_id` and then somehow only display one of each, but when I add a `group('magazine_id`) I get a `PG::Error column "issues.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer [PostgreSQL -must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18061285/postgresql-must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause-or-be-used-in-an-aggregate-functi?answertab=active#answer-20239490)

which lead me to `select("DISTINCT_ON('magazine_id') *")`. Works perfectly, only showing a single entry for each `magazine_id`

```
def index
  @issues = Issue
    .includes(:magazine)
    .select("DISTINCT ON (magazine_id, magazines.subscriptions_count) *")
    .order('comics.subscriptions_count DESC')
    .paginate(page: @page, per_page: 25)
end
```