# Cannot perform group operating in rails active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am trying to perform group_by operation on my rails model,but there seem to be some problem. I have a model named student as

```
class CreateStudents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :students do |t|
      t.integer :student_id
      t.string :department
      t.integer :maths
      t.integer :physics
      t.integer :chemistry
      t.string :year

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

On rails console when I run

```
 s = Student.all.group("date(created_at)")
```

I have the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "students.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT "students".* FROM "students" GROUP BY date(created_at...
               ^
: SELECT "students".* FROM "students" GROUP BY date(created_at)
```

However when I run

```
 s = Student.all.group("date(created_at)").count
```

it runs successfully.

I am a new to rails.

Rails 4.2.6
Ruby 2.3.1

Comment: Possible Duplicate [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18061285/postgresql-must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause-or-be-used-in-an-aggregate-functi)

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect to be a result of `group` without `count`?

Imagine you have a table:

```
   id | created_at
——————|———————————
    1 | 2016-06-12
    2 | 2016-06-12
    3 | 2016-06-12
    4 | 2016-06-13
    5 | 2016-06-13
```

Now with `count` the result would be:

```
count | created_at
——————|———————————
    3 | 2016-06-12
    2 | 2016-06-13
```

But without `count` there is a collision (first column value is undetermined.)

The problem has nothing to do with Rails, it is a typical SQL problem with non well-formed aggregation. Please share, what you actually wanted to achieve (to receive as a result of this operation.)

Whether you want to group the result *on Ruby side*, get the array and group it with Ruby [`Enumerable#group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), on the array instance (please note, this is **rather inefficient**):

```
Model.all.group_by &:created_at
```

Comment: I want all the fields grouped by  `created_at`. Please tell me how to achieve that if I am wrong. 
I want average marks of all student with same student_id

Comment: What do you mean “all the fields”? Given the very simple input data I provided, what would be the desired result?

Comment: I want average marks of every student with same student_id, can I do that?

Comment: Why would you group by `created_at` if you need _averages_ for _id_?? `Student.group_by(:student_id).average(:maths)` would do. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html

Comment: can I find average for multiple fields like? 
`Student.group(:student_id).average(:maths, :physics)`?

Comment: `group_by` should be `group` in the above comment!

Comment: The only possibility I am aware of is to use plain SQL: `Student.connection.execute "SELECT AVG(...), AVG(...) FROM students GROUP BY student_id"`.

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
 s = Student.group(:created_at)
```

If you want to use `group` instead of `group_by` then don't use `all` because it returns array of objects.

using `group_by`:

```
s = Student.all.group_by(&:created_at)
```

Comment: The former produces the very same error due to reasons I described in my answer, the latter is _grouping_ the array on the ruby/client side.