# rails impressionist how to find 5 of most view item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, impressionist

I using this instance to find more view 5 Item, but cannot get the result.
Can teach me how to get it?

```
 @test = Item.limit(5).joins(:impressions).group("impressions.impressionable_id").order("count(impressions.impressionable_id) DESC")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the using [counter cache](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist#adding-a-counter-cache). In this approach you've to create a new column to your `model` and add some configuration to your model. Thus, the gem will automatically update the view count.

Or, (not tested, but should work)

```
Item.joins(:impressions).group("impressions.impressionable_id").order("count(impression‌​s.id) DESC").first(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

in your CreatePosts migration:

```
t.integer :visits, default: 0
```

in your post.rb:

```
is_impressionable counter_cache: true, column_name: :visits, :unique => :all
```

then:

```
Post.order(visits: :asc).limit(5)
```

And this thingy still works for rendering the count inside your post (Slim):

```
= post.impressionist_count
```

And yes, this works in PostreSQL and has no problem with activeadmin (quite handy for Dashboard)
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by Emu wouldn't work if you are using PostgreSQL. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18061285/postgresql-must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause-or-be-used-in-an-aggregate-functi) for explanation.

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "items.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Just add the primary key column of `Item` table and everything should work!

```
Item.joins(:impressions).
     group("items.id, impressions.impressionable_id").
     order("count(impression‌​s.id) DESC").
     first(5)
```