# knex SQL - column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I am using postgres and knex with NodeJS to aggregate session_ids by hours in a given date range. My start_timestamp is in format`2016-12-12 14:53:17.243-05`. I want to group all records by the hour such that:

- Hour `14:00:00-15:00:00` would have n records within that hour.
- Hour `15:00:00-16:00:00` would have n records within that hour.
- etc...

Given the query

```
db.knex.count('t1.id as session_ids')
    .from('sessions as t1')
    .where(db.knex.raw('t1.start_timestamp'), '>=', startDate)
    .andWhere(db.knex.raw('t1.start_timestamp'), '<=', endDate)
    .groupByRaw("date_trunc('hour', t1.start_timestamp)");
```

My start date and end date dictate a range of 1 Day. So there shouldn't be duplicate/ambiguous times based on grouping by hour of the day.

I am succesfully able to get counts of each record by the hour:

```
[ anonymous { session_ids: '6' },
  anonymous { session_ids: '1' },
  anonymous { session_ids: '1' },
  anonymous { session_ids: '3' },
  ...
```

But I need their actual time displayed, as such:

```
{
    hour: 10
    session_ids: 5 //5 session IDs 
}
```

Adding `.select('t1.start_timestamp')` below `count`, as shown [in this example](http://www.dofactory.com/sql/group-by), I get the following error:

> Unhandled rejection error: column "t1.start_timestamp" must appear in
>   the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

This error doesn't make sense to me as `t1.start_timestamp` appears in the GROUP BY stage.

Moreover, I've already checked out [PostgreSQL -must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18061285/postgresql-must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause-or-be-used-in-an-aggregate-functi) for help. I don't have ambiguity in my records so the DB should know which records to select.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, do you resolved it?

Comment: was able to solve it by adding select statement

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with knex, but the following query does not work (it gives the same error message you noted):

```
SELECT t1.start_timestamp, count(t1.id) AS session_ids
FROM sessions AS t1
GROUP BY date_trunc('hour', t1.start_timestamp);
```

However, the following query does work:

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour', t1.start_timestamp), count(t1.id) AS session_ids
FROM sessions AS t1
GROUP BY date_trunc('hour', t1.start_timestamp);
```

Can you try changing .select accordingly?